# Why we can't build decentralized applications upon Bitcoin?

Tags: blockchain, dapp-development, bitcoin, decentralization, consensus-by-block

I have recently gotten into blockchain development and reading from different sources, watching videos I've incurred that we have been building major De-Fi projects, applications upon Ethereum, EVMs such as BSC and PLoygon, Solana, iota, etc. but we can only transfer Bitcoin from wallet to wallet and not build upon it. We can only develop, fast and lightning wallets and servers for Bitcoin such as Electrum, electrs, etc.
So, why exactly can't we develop any decentralized applications upon Bitcoin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitcoin simply doesn't support the kind of programs that are needed for stuff like DeFi. Bitcoin has some scripting support, but it's very limited and can't really be used for anything complicated.

Ethereum's Solidity is a turing complete language, which means it can, in theory, used to build anything. Bitcoin's scripts are far from that.